# unable to bind to property 'xmlnode' on class 'XML' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i am using xmllistcollection for displaying data in list.
whenever i run my application data is display in list control, but this warning has displayed in console.
How can i remove this warning
**warning: unable to bind to property 'xmlnode' on class 'XML' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)**

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectProxy

```
[Bindable] public var objProxy:ObjectProxy = new ObjectProxy(xmllistcollection);
```

Set ur dataprovider as objProxy.

Comment: [Bindable]
public var scheduleXmlListCollection:XMLListCollection;
private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
  var scheduleXmlList:XMLList = new XMLList(event.result.data);
  scheduleXmlListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
  scheduleXmlListCollection.source = scheduleXmlList;
}

<s:List id="listResult" dataProvider="{resultsXmlListCollection}"
width="40%" height="100%">
<s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>       <ui:resultlistitem width="100%" height="75" data1="{data.@data1}"
data2="{data.@data2}" data3="{data.@data3}" /></fx:Component>
</s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>

Comment: I have xmllistcollection of type XMLListCollection; whit this answer, the flash builder gives me the following error:
    cannot convert mx.utils::ObjectProxy@31bec81 to mx.collections.IList.